# Is it possible to have a derived class that inherits a final function but creates the same function (not override)?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, final, virtual-functions

I have a problem with a `final` function. I want to "stop" the polymorphism in a class but I still want to generate the same function in a derived class.

Something like this:

```
class Base{
    protected:
        int _x, _y;
    public:
        Base(int x = 0, int y = 0) : _x(x), _y(y){};
        int x() const { return _x; }
        int y() const { return _y; }
        virtual void print()const{ cout << _x*_y << endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base{
    public:
        Derived(int x = 0, int y = 0) : Base(x, y){}
        void print()const final { cout << _x*_y / 2.0 << endl; } // final inheritance
};

class NonFinal : public Derived{
        void print()const{ cout << "apparently im not the last..." << endl } 
    // here i want a new function. not overriding the final function from Derived class
};
```

Comment: As a general rule, I would call a design bug on code that hides inherited members (with the obvious exception of overriding an inherited virtual function). I would suggest calling the method something else in `NonFinal`. If you find yourself needing to do this, something about your OO design is bad.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is an experimental question, since actually you should rethink what you are doing when you require to "override a final function" (sounds contradicting, doesn't it?).

But you could introduce a "dummy"-parameter, i.e. `void NonFinal::print(int test=0)const`, which let's the compiler treat the member function as a different one. Not sure if that solves your "problem"; but at least it introduces a function with the same name, which can still be called without passing an argument, and which is separated from the ones of `Derived` and `Base`.

```
class NonFinal : public Derived{
public:
    void print(int test=0)const{ cout << "apparently im not the last..." << endl; }
};

int main() {

    Base b (10,10);
    Derived d (20,20);
    NonFinal nf;
    Base *bPtr = &d;
    bPtr->print();  // gives 200
    bPtr = &nf; // gives 0
    bPtr->print();
    nf.print(); // gives "apparantly..."
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but it's not possible to create a function in a derived class when a function with the same name exists as `final` in the base class. You'll need to rethink your design.

The problem stems from the fact that a function declaration in a derived class with the same name as a function in a base class is treated as an attempt to override whether the `override` keyword is present or not (for historical reasons, I presume). So you can't "turn off" overriding.

Here's a relevant standard quote:

§ 10.3/4 [class.virtual]

> If a virtual function `f` in some class `B` is marked with the *virt-specifier* `final` and in a class `D` derived from `B` a function `D::f` overrides `B::f`, the program is ill-formed. [ Example:

```
struct B {
   virtual void f() const final;
};
struct D : B {
   void f() const; // error: D::f attempts to override final B::f
};
```

> —end